# Chart with slider to move time dimension values for SSAS cube data

Tags: asp.net, time, ssas, charts

Is there any good interactive chart solution that can be used to display cube data as the time dimension is changed with slider control. Preferably ASP.NET solution, but can also be Silverlight or Flash (if can be easily integrated with .NET). Something close to this as seen in following URL: http://www.cbs.nl/en-GB/menu/themas/vrije-tijd-cultuur/cijfers/extra/gasten-en-overnachtingen-per-accommodatietype.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [chart controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) in .NET 4.0